SOFT QUESTION: MS in statistics (computational statistics specialisation) vs MS in CS(data science specialisation)
Question
I aim to pursue a PhD in ML/deep learning from a top university in the US/Europe. Should I choose an M.Stat or an M.Tech in CS from the Indian Statistical Institute to strengthen my PhD application and research foundation?
Background
I hold a BS-MS in pure mathematics and wish to build a solid foundation before applying for a PhD. I am equally interested in computational statistics and data science. The Indian Statistical Institute is highly regarded for its statistical programs but less so for CS. I seek advice on which master's degree would be more attractive to PhD committees and better equip me for impactful research in ML/deep learning.
PS: If this question is not meant for here, please tell me the appropriate platform, I will post it there. Thanks for your patience. Apology for the trouble caused.

If only it was easy: Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?
